# Reading numbers from text file doesn't work

Tags: java, file, file-io

I'm trying to read numbers from a next file and figure out the biggest number in the file however I've been getting the wrong answer. The file has a bunch of numbers seperated by a space and after a while a new line is made. When I check my output of `max` I can see it getting smaller and larger which shouldn't be happening so I think maybe it's something to do with only comparing the current line? I've seen that people add the numbers to a list and then I could order them and grab the last index but why doesn't this way work?

```java
int max = 0;
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (in.hasNextInt()) {
        if (in.nextInt() > max) {
            max = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
System.out.println(max);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(in.nextInt() > max) {
    max = in.nextInt();
}
```

Every time you invoke the nextInt() method you read an integer value from the file, so you end up skipping every second integer.

Try something like:

```
int value = in.nextInt();

if(value > max) {
    max = value;
}
```